# Stripe Connect IOS Integration

Tags: swift, xcode, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

**Stripe** has provided no documentation for integration Stripe Connect for an IOS app. The Stripe Connect implementation does not allow for `URL Schemes` for the redirect url hence I'm not sure how one would open the url WITHIN THE APP and redirect to the app while getting the redirect url with authorization code.

Any help would be appreciated. How do I approach this?

Comment: this may be help >> https://stripe.com/docs/connect/quickstart

Comment: I have the same question! :/ How did you solve this, Stephen?

Answer (score -2):

1- First you need to import stripe to your project:

`import Stripe`

2- Make a pay button to execute payment action:

```
@IBOutlet weak var payButton: UIButton!
```

3- Make an instance of stripe text field to handle card data input:

```
class StripePaymentViewController: UIViewController {
    //stripe payment textfield
    let paymentTexField = STPPaymentCardTextField() 
}
```

4- In viewDidLoad you may initialize the textField:

```
func initializeStripeTextField() {
    // Initialize textField size
    paymentTexField.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width - 30, height: 60)
    // Changing textField background color
    paymentTexField.backgroundColor = .white
    // Setting the delegate (will be implemented later)
    paymentTexField.delegate = self
    // Adding the textField to the view
    view.addSubview(paymentTexField)
    // optional: hide the button until the payment data entered
    payButton.isHidden = true
}
```

5- Implement the stripe textField delegate to show the hidden button after filling the card data

```
extension StripePaymentViewController: STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {
    func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
        if textField.isValid {
            payButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

6- Add the pay button action with 'YOUR_STRIPE_KEY':

```
@IBAction func payAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Get the card parameters
        let card = paymentTexField.cardParams

        // Aquire stripe token
        STPAPIClient.init(publishableKey: "YOUR_STRIPE_KEY").createToken(withCard: card) { (token, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print (error)
            } else if let token = token {
                // The aquired token
                print (token)
                // Send payment request (will be implemented later)
                self.payUsingToken(token: token)
            }
        }
    }
```

7- Make payment request using Alamofire

```
func payUsingToken(token: STPToken) {
        let baseUrl = "YOUR_BACKEND_PAYMENT_URL"
        // Request parameters
        var parameters = [String: String]()
        // Stripe aquired token
        parameters["pay_token"] = token.tokenId
        // The payment amount in cents (500 == 5$)
        parameters["money_amount"] = String(500 * 100)
        // Add other parameters if you want ...

        Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default) .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                //Success
                print(JSON)

            case .failure(let error):
                //Failure
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can take a reference from here: https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=LaWyTWUCpb8